# Update with save() method doesn't work in django

Tags: python, django, rest

I'm using multiple connections to different databases. But nothing happen when I'm trying to update data in db using save() method. I mean everything's works but data still not updated.
How can I fix it?

```
def save_object_using_dynamic_db(model, obj_id, db_alias, **kwargs):
    """
    Save an object into the specified database alias.
    """
    connection = connections[db_alias]
    print(f"{connection = }")

    try:
        obj_to_save = model.objects.using(connection.alias).get(id=obj_id)
    except model.DoesNotExist:
        # If the object doesn't exist, you may want to handle this case accordingly
        print(f"Object with id {obj_id} does not exist in the database.")
        return None

    for field, value in kwargs.items():
        if hasattr(obj_to_save, field):
            print(f"{obj_to_save = }, {obj_id = }, {field = }: {value = }")
            setattr(obj_to_save, field, value)

    try:
        # obj_to_save.full_clean()  # Check model validation
        obj_to_save.save(using=connection.alias)
        print(f"Object saved: {obj_to_save}")
        return obj_to_save
    except ValidationError as e:
        print(f"Validation error: {e}")
        return None
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Unexpected error: {e}")
        return None

    # obj_to_save.save(using=db_alias)
    # print(f"{obj_to_save = }")
    # return obj_to_save
```